# Cannot register my .ocx with error code 0x80040200

Tags: ocx, regsvr32, dllregistration

When i try to register my .ocx file I get error code 0x80040200.

I know that this error usually occurs when I got no administrator privileges, but for me that's not the case.

I found some [code snippet](https://codepad.co/snippet/FCc3G6kC#) with which I could test my .ocx wether regsvr32 can find the entry point and it looks like it could.

Is there any other known reason why this error could occur?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case, I tried to register dll and got the same error. The reason was absence of a tlb file near the dll.